# Is it possible to read dos files in linux using an ifstream

Tags: c++

When I use the std::ifstream to open a file that has been written in dos format, the ifstream does not seem to be able to open the file correctly since when I call good() on the stream afterwards it fails (returns false).  I tried opening the file in binary mode as well as the default "in" mode and neither worked.  If I convert the file to unix using dos2unix, everything works fine.

The goal behind being able to do this is that I want to be able to read a file and parse it, but I cannot guarantee that the file has not been saved in dos (Windows) or unix (Linux) format. Ideally, I would like to be able to use the ifstream.

Any suggestions?

Thanks!

Comment: @Chubsdad:  Why are you editing the post so that regular sentences are fixed-width?  The fixed-width formatting is useful for (and intended mostly for) code snippets and related text, not for random sentences...

Comment: @James McNellis: I wanted to highlight that portion related to 'dos2unix'. How should I have done that?

Comment: Why don't you post the code you're using to open the file and check the stream state?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The file format will **NOT** affect your ability to open it.

It is more likely that your path is not correct.

Comment: Is the post about Ctrl+M characters? the post also mentions that doing dos2unix works fine. So it's not about path I guess. Highlighted the post appropriately

Comment: Ctrl-M character will not affect the way ifstream's work. It is more likely that the filename was changed from a bad name to a good name. Is the file system case sensitive?

Answer (score 1):

It seems extremely unlikely that GCC would do such a thing.

I suggest doing `my_ifstream.exceptions( ios::failbit | ios::badbit );` before opening it, and running in the debugger. Then you can see where it ceased to be good.

Also, opening the file in binary mode `(ios::in | ios::binary)` should eliminate any possibility of the implementation being choosy over the contents of the file.